# how to extract modularity scores for each partition in a walktrap community?

Tags: r, plot, graph, modularity

I am new to Community Detection and to make things harder I am also a beginner in R - please keep this in mind when you kindly answer.
I am happy to add my data to this post if anyone could tell me how to achieve that please?

#### First Problem

I created a directed graph with 2198 nodes and 1380771 edges with weights (weights are contained in mylinks):

```
library(igraph)
net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=mylinks, vertices=mynodes, directed=T)
```

I then use the walktrap algorithm to create communities:

```
com <- walktrap.community(net, weights = E(net)$weight, steps = 4, merges =
                        TRUE, modularity = TRUE)
```

Walktrap splits the graph into 10 communities and gives me a modularity score of 0.4819893 (which I think is quite good):

```
length(com) #  number of communities: 10 
modularity(com) # how modular the graph partitioning is
```

I can plot a dendrogram with the 10 communities on top:

```
dendrogram <- dendPlot(com, mode="hclust")
```

Now my question: I need access to the modularity scores and memberships for all levels, not just the best cut level with 10 communities. So basically I want to be able to cut my dendrogram at each level and calculate the modularity as well as get the membership. How do I do this best please?
I am after something like this:

- Level    Modularity
- 1       ?
- 2       ?
- 3       ?
- ...     ...
- 10      0.4819893
- ...     ...

This list should include as many levels as the graph has nodes. Then in addition there should be something which shows me the membership for each level.

#### Second Problem

The second problem I have is to visualize this graph, as it contains so many nodes and edges that one can't really see anything:

```
com_plot <- plot(com, net)
```

*Plotted graph with communities:*
[image]

I would be glad for any ideas and solutions on this front.

Thank you for reading all this!